# Создание маски через CSS?

Tags: css, css-mask

Начал значит недавно изучать такую тему, как макирование через CSS. Пытаюсь **наложить маску на объект**, но она почему-то не работает (или работает но не так, как задумал я). Помогите, подскажите, что ж я делаю не так?

*Вот код который я использовал:*

**HTML**

```
<div class="rect">
 <div class="mask"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.rect{
    width: 450px;
    height: 185px;

    background: url(rect.png);
    background-size: cover;

    border: 2px solid red;
}
.mask{
    mask: url("gamestart.png");
    -webkit-mask: url("gamestart.png");
    mask-size: cover;
    -webkit-mask-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
}
```

*Изображения:*

[image: Прямоугольник]

[image: Маска]

Comment: Добавьте [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте указывать маску тому же элементу, который вы хотите "замаскировать".

```css
.rect{
    width: 450px;
    height: 185px;

    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/t52JS.png);
    mask: url(https://i.ibb.co/RcSdQ7f/1.png);
    -webkit-mask: url(https://i.ibb.co/RcSdQ7f/1.png);
    mask-size: cover;
    -webkit-mask-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="rect">
 <div class="mask"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Но я бы хотел уточнить - почему не работает вариант с локальным использованием изображений? Например я прописал какой-то **background: url (bg.png)** - он отобразился. Прописал **mask: url(mask.svg)** и -**webkit-mask: url(mask.svg)** - не отобразился.

Comment: @Urarak вы бы могли предоставить пример с файлами? тяжело понять, в чем дело